# What's with all the users with 101 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

Why does this site have a load of people with rep of 101 who haven't asked/answered any questions?  Am I missing some Stack Exchange new user policy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You start with 1 reputation point. If you link your user account to an account on another Stack Exchange site you get a free 100 point bonus.

Thus 101 reputation without asking any questions or giving any answers.

***Update***: Note that the account you link to has to have a minimum amount of reputation itself (200+) or you don't get the bonus. The thinking is that if you're a good contributor on another site that will likely be true on this one as well.

[Linked account didn't get 100 rep points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50503/linked-account-didnt-get-100-rep-points)

Comment: I have linked to other stack exchange accounts and I didn't get the bump.  Is that because I was in the private beta?

Comment: No. It's because none of your other accounts have over 200 reputation.

Comment: i don't get +100 either. my SO account has like 600 reps. Do you know why?

Comment: According to your profile http://android.stackexchange.com/users/136?tab=accounts#tab-top you haven't linked to your SO account. Different login credentials perhaps? It won't help you now anyway; you've been here too long. You needed to link when you created the account (or shortly thereafter).

Comment: @Al E. - That is not true. If you relink your accounts later you'll still get the bonus.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.